# What is wrong with the add method?

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

I'm currently working on a simple program regarding content provider in Android. I created my own content provider using SQLite database, in which i store and handle my friends'birthdays. The app run fine but when i add a birthday the app crashes. But when i start the app again i can show the birthday that was added from another method `showMybirthDays()`.

```
public void addTheBirthday(View v) {
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(MyBirthProvider.NAME,
                ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.name)).getText().toString());
        values.put(MyBirthProvider.BIRTHDAY,
                ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.birthday)).getText().toString());
        Uri uri = getContentResolver().insert(MyBirthProvider.MYCONTENT_URI, v);

        Toast.makeText(this, uri.toString() + "inserted!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

I tried the toast without `uri.toString()` and it works. So the problem is `uri.toString()`, but i cant not find where i did wrong? - I stuck simply
Any help is very appreciated. Thanks.

Here is my `CONTENT_URI`:

```
static final String URL = "content://" + MYPROVIDER_NAME + "/myfriends/" + ID;
static final Uri MYCONTENT_URI = Uri.parse(URL);
```

Here is my provider:

```
public class MyBirthProvider extends ContentProvider {

    static final String ID = "id";
    static final String NAME = "name";
    static final String BIRTHDAY = "birthday";

    static final String PROVIDER_NAME = "com.example.test.provider.Birthday";
    static final String URL = "content://" + MYPROVIDER_NAME + "/myfriends/" + ID;
    static final Uri MYCONTENT_URI = Uri.parse(URL);

    static final int FRIENDS = 1;
    static final int FRIENDS_ID = 2;

    DBHelper dbHelper;

    private static HashMap<String, String> BirthMap;

    static final UriMatcher uriMatcher;

    static {
        uriMatcher = new UriMatcher(UriMatcher.NO_MATCH);
        uriMatcher.addURI(PROVIDER_NAME, "friends", FRIENDS);
        uriMatcher.addURI(PROVIDER_NAME, "friends/#", FRIENDS_ID);
    }

    private SQLiteDatabase database;
    static final String DATABASE_NAME = "MyBirthdayReminder";
    static final String TABLE_NAME = "mybirthTable";
    static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    static final String CREATE_TABLE = " CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + " (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
            " name TEXT NOT NULL, " + " birthday TEXT NOT NULL);";

    private static class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

        public DBHelper(Context context) {
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);

        }

        @Override
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {
            sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE);
        }

        @Override
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            Log.w(DBHelper.class.getName(), "Upgrading database frim version " + oldVersion + " to "
                    + newVersion + " .Old data will be destroyed");
            sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
            onCreate(sqLiteDatabase);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreate() {
        Context c = getContext();
        dbHelper = new DBHelper(c);
        database = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();

        if (database == null)
            return false;
        else
            return true;
    }

    @Override
    public Cursor query(Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection, String[] selectionArgs, String sortOrder) {
        SQLiteQueryBuilder qb = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();
        qb.setTables(TABLE_NAME);

        switch (uriMatcher.match(uri)) {
            case FRIENDS:
                qb.setProjectionMap(BirthMap);
                break;
            case FRIENDS_ID:
                qb.appendWhere(ID + "=" + uri.getLastPathSegment());
                break;
            default:
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown URI" + uri);
        }
        if (sortOrder == null || sortOrder == "") {
            sortOrder = NAME;
        }
        Cursor cursor = qb.query(database, projection, selection, selectionArgs, null, null, sortOrder);

        return cursor;
    }

    @Override
    public Uri insert(Uri uri, ContentValues values) {
        long row = database.insert(TABLE_NAME, "", values);

        if (row > 0) {
            Uri newUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(MYCONTENT_URI, row);
            getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(newUri, null);
            return null;
        }
        throw new SQLException("Fail to add a new record into " + uri);
    }

    @Override
    public int update(Uri uri, ContentValues values, String selection, String[] selectionArgs) {
        int count = 0;

        switch (uriMatcher.match(uri)) {
            case FRIENDS:
                count = database.update(TABLE_NAME, values, ID + " = " + uri.getLastPathSegment() +
                        (!TextUtils.isEmpty(selection) ? " AND (" + selection + ')' : ""), selectionArgs);
                break;
            default:
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unsupported URI " + uri);
        }
        getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null);
        return count;
    }

    @Override
    public int delete(Uri uri, String selection, String[] selectionArgs) {
        int count = 0;
        switch (uriMatcher.match(uri)) {
            case FRIENDS:
                count = database.delete(TABLE_NAME, selection, selectionArgs);
                break;
            case FRIENDS_ID:
                String id = uri.getLastPathSegment(); //gets the id
                count = database.delete(TABLE_NAME, ID + " = " + id + (!TextUtils.isEmpty(selection)
                        ? " AND (" + selection + ')' : ""), selectionArgs);
                break;
            default:
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unsupported URI " + uri);
        }

        getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null);
        return count;
    }

    @Override
    public String getType(Uri uri) {
        switch (uriMatcher.match(uri)) {
            case FRIENDS:
                return "vnd.android.cursor.dir/vnd.example.friends";
            case FRIENDS_ID:
                return "vnd.android.cursor.dir/vnd.example.friends";
            default:
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unsupported URI " + uri);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Post your log file pls

Comment: Your question conditions are too broad. Very likely the reason why your code works if you comment out Toast is that because your uri is null, that is, insert returns null instead of uri appended with id (that's how it is supposed to be). You should provide more details on how your content provider is implemented to receive complete answer.

Comment: Instance of `ContentValues` you have created is `v` then why are using `values` name to add in Db?

Comment: the problem is your `ContentProvider` and you did not post code for it..

Comment: I have just posted my provider.

Comment: Any time your app crashes you should look at the logcat output to figure out why.

Comment: from logcat:  Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.example.test.contetprovidertest.MainActivity.addTheBirthday(MainActivity.java:62)